# How do I capture the entire HTML page (including overflow) in a UIWebView?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, xcode6.1

The code below captures the screen but not the entire page of the web view:

```
func screenShotMethod() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

How do I capture the entire HTML page (including overflow) in a UIWebView?

Comment: Make height bigger for both webview and context.

Comment: I am new at this.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late but this one could help someone else:

```
let webViewFrame = uiWebViewObj.frame
let scrollViewOffset = uiWebViewObj.scrollView.contentOffset
if webView.scrollView.contentSize.width == 0 || webView.scrollView.contentSize.height == 0{
  // nothing to take screenshot of 
}
//Set the scrollView offset to top of the web Page
uiWebViewObj.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -webView.scrollView.contentInset.top), animated: false)
let screenRect =  UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
uiWebViewObj.frame = CGRectMake(webViewFrame.origin.x, webViewFrame.origin.y, screenRect.size.width, uiWebViewObj.scrollView.contentSize.height)
 let cgSizeToUse = CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, uiWebViewObj.scrollView.contentSize.height)
autoreleasepool{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cgSizeToUse, false, 0) 
    uiWebViewObj.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

uiWebViewObj.frame = webViewFrame
uiWebObj.scrollView.contentOffset = scrollViewOffset
```

Reference link:
    http://swiftgazelle.com/2015/08/how-to-take-uiwebview-screenshot-in-swift-on-ios/